# Performance of smart pointer and raw pointer in containers

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm curious about the answer to this question as I mostly work with containers.
which one is more logical to use in minimum of 100 (and maximum of 10k) elements in vector or map container in?

- `std:::vector<std::unique_ptr<(struct or class name)>>`
- `std:::vector<std::shared_ptr<(struct or class name)>>`
- `std:::vector<(struct or class name)*>`

Machine detais: FreeBSD 12.1 + clang-devel or gcc11.

Comment: Pick the fourth option by default: `std:::vector<(struct or class name)>`

Comment: @davidhigh why? i don't understand fully this whenever i look at big projects (like game) developers usually use `std::vector<(struct or class name)*>` what is the reason of this?

Comment: This depends on what the `class` or `struct` is and how you are using it and how you are using the vector.

Comment: Expanding on above: unless you have a really good reason, like polymorphism, let the container contain the data. Fewer pointers means less pointer-chasing and usually better cache usage.

Comment: ***big projects (like game) developers usually use std::vector<(struct or class name)*>*** May be because of using polymorphism but there are other valid reasons to do that.

Comment: @WayneCox I don't know what game code you looked at, but there is never any use of `std::vector` in commercial game engines, it's always custom containers. And if it is a dynamic array of pointers, then there is usually a good reason *why* they are pointers

Comment: Could be many. A pointer can be polymorph, is nullable, and can have advantages in compile efficiency (pimpl idiom). But maybe it's just because many people tend to write C under the hood of C++. Without clear and a-priori known reasons, stick to tje option in my comment (often called RAII).

Comment: @davidhigh: `std::vector<class>` wastes a lot of memory if `class` is large and the vector is mostly empty.  But on the other hand, if it's sparse then `std::map<int, class>` might be better.

Comment: A note on `shared_ptr`: Don't use it unless you have multiple legitimate owners of a resource. 1) supporting that sharing, especially where threading may be involved, has overhead. If you don't need it, don't pay it. 2) You're sending the wrong signals to other programmers and they will code appropriately in response to those signals rather than the reality you've inadvertently concealed. This may turn out to be harmless, but bad assumptions tend to insert bugs and inefficiencies.

Comment: so if i don't using polymorph in my class or struct i must can `std::vector<(struct or class name)>` is it true my friends?

Comment: Not quite. Where we're going is you should have a good reason. There are many good reasons, too many to list, and polymorphism is merely a very common reason. In the comments size, sparcity, and data hiding were brought up as other good reasons. You'll find more. But if you don't have a good reason, let the container do its job and contain. If there is no obvious reason, testing and profiling will show you if an alternative is necessary.

Comment: @NateEldrege: there's now std:optional for this case, that is one can use `std:vector<std:optional<...>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really opinion-based, but I'll describe the rules of thumb I use.

`std:::vector<(struct or class name)>` is my default unless I have specific requirements that are not met by that option.    More specifically, it is my go-to option UNLESS at least one of the following conditions are true;

- `struct or class name` is polymorphic and instances of classes derived from `struct or class name` need to be stored in the vector.
- `struct or class name` does not comply with the rule of three (before C++11), the rule of five (from C++11), OR the rule of zero
- there are SPECIFIC *requirements* to dynamically manage lifetime of instances of `struct or class name`

The above criteria amount to "use `std::vector<(struct or class name)>` if `struct or class name` meets requirements to be an element of a standard container".

If `struct or class name` is polymorphic AND there is a requirement that the vector contain instances of derived classes my default choice is `std:::vector<std::unique_ptr<(struct or class name)> >`.   i.e. none of the options mentioned in the question.

I will only go past that choice if there are special requirements for managing lifetime of the objects in the vector that aren't met by either  `std:::vector<(struct or class name)>` or `std:::vector<std::unique_ptr<(struct or class name)> >`.

Practically, the above meets the vast majority of real-world needs.

If there is a need for two unrelated pieces of code to have control over the lifetime of objects stored in a vector then (and only then) I will consider `std:::vector<std::shared_ptr<(struct or class name)> >`.   The premise is that there will be some code that doesn't have access to our vector, but has access to its elements via (for example) being passed a `std::shared_ptr<(struct or class name)>`.

Now, I get to the case which is VERY rare in my experience - where there are *requirements* to manage lifetime of objects that aren't properly handled by `std:::vector<(struct or class name)>`, `std:::vector<std::unique_ptr<(struct or class name)> >`, or by `std:::vector<std::shared_ptr<(struct or class name)> >`.

In that case, and only that case, I will - and only if I'm desperate - use `std:::vector<(struct or class name)*>`.   This is the situation to be avoided, as much as possible.   To give you an idea of how bad I think this option is, I've been known to change *other* system-level requirements in a quest to avoid this option.   The reason I avoid this option like the plague is that it becomes necessary to write and debug EVERY bit of code that explicitly manages the lifetime of each `struct or class name`.   This includes writing `new` expressions everywhere, ensuring every `new` expression is eventually matched by a corresponding `delete` expression.   This option also means there is a need to debug hand-written code to ensure no object is `delete`d twice (undefined behaviour) and every object is `delete`d once (i.e. avoid leaks).    In other words, this option involves lots of effort and - in non-trivial situations - is really hard to get working correctly.

Comment: **+1** for the 3 points mentioned at the beginning of your answer. However, it would be nicer if you also provided some insights regarding possible performance differences between these approaches.

Comment: Plus one, but shouldn't it be "UNLESS (at least) ONE of the three conditions is true"? You can have polymorphism and at the same time perfectly comply to the rule of five, for example, and you'd still use a pointer.

Comment: @davidhigh   Thinking about it, you're right.   I'll update shortly.

Comment: @digito_evo  The performance differences (in terms of speed or resource usage) don't actually mean much.   If a vector of objects is suitable, using pointers (or smart pointers) adds additional levels of indirection, so is unlikely to improve performance.   If indirection is required (e.g. the class is polymorphic) then it's required.   Raw pointers don't typically offer blinding performance improvements over a suitable smart pointer without accepting a significant risk of the code behaving incorrectly (or effort to correct that).

Comment: This answer promotes unnecessary fear of using raw pointers. Lists of pointers like `std::vector<whatever*>` are perfectly fine when there is no ownership. That is, when some another unrelated container owns the objects, guaranteeing that the pointers are not dangling. In complicated systems, such lists of pointers should appear all the time.

Comment: @anatolyg   I'm not promoting fear of using raw pointers.   I'm explaining why alternative approaches (over having a vector of pointers to a structure) are often preferable.      And having a container of pointers and an "unrelated container" that contains the corresponding objects tends to make for complicated interrelationships between code that uses (or operates on) either container - which, I maintain, is more difficult to get right (because, among other things, it makes the program as a whole more complicated).

Answer (score 3):

Start with correct behavior, not performance.

1. Does your container own your objects? If no, use raw pointers. If yes, use smart pointers. But which ones? See below.
2. Do you need to support several containers containing the same object, and is it unclear which container will be deleted first? If the answer to both is "yes", use `shared_ptr`. Otherwise, use `unique_ptr`.

Later, if you discover that accessing the smart pointers wastes too much time (unlikely), replace the smart pointers by raw pointers together with highly optimized memory management, which you will have to implement according to your specific needs.

---

As noted in comments, you could do it without pointers. So, before applying this answer, ask yourself why you need pointers at all (I guess the answer is polymorphism, but not sure).

Comment: thank u so much, i don't have polymorphism in my class or struct and i guess i will use `std::vector<(class or struct name)>`

Comment: Those who are guaranteed to not be deleted last should just be raw pointers. If any is guaranteed deleted last, that should be a unique_ptr. If one in a groups is guaranteed to be deleted last, but you don't know which, those are shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide a firm solution to your question without seeing the context and the way your struct/class operates.
But I still want to provide some basic info about smart pointers so hopefully, you can make a wise decision.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main( )
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        int a;
        double b;
    };

    std::cout << "Size of unique_ptr: " << sizeof( std::unique_ptr< MyStruct > ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Size of shared_ptr: " << sizeof( std::shared_ptr< MyStruct > ) << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> > vec1; // a container holding unique pointers
    std::vector< MyStruct* > vec2; // another container holding raw pointers

    vec1.emplace_back( std::make_unique<MyStruct>(2, 3.6) ); // deletion process automatically handled
    vec2.emplace_back( new MyStruct(5, 11.2) ); // you'll have to manually delete all objects later

    std::cout << vec1[0]->a << ' ' << vec1[0]->b << '\n';
    std::cout << vec2[0]->a << ' ' << vec2[0]->b << '\n';
}
```

The possible output:

```
Size of unique_ptr: 8
Size of shared_ptr: 16

2 3.6
5 11.2
```

Check the assembly output [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sM6W3jvc3) and compare the two containers. As I saw, they generate the exact same code.

The `unique_ptr` is very fast. I don't think it has any overhead. However, the `shared_ptr` has a bit of overhead due to its reference counting mechanism. But it still might be more efficient than a handwritten reference counting system. Don't underestimate the facilities provided in the STL. Use them in most cases except the ones in which STL does not exactly perform the specific task you need.

Speaking of performance, `std::vector<(struct or class name)>` is better in most cases since all the objects are stored in a contiguous block of heap memory, and also dereferencing them is not required.
However, when using a container of pointers, your objects will be scattered around heap memory and your program will be less cache-friendly.

Comment: thank u so much for example! What do u think `std::vector<(struct or class name)>` vs `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<(struct or class name)>>` for performance?

Comment: @Wayne Cox Yes, it can be significantly faster. Read my updated answer.